# use babel-jest for jest but still get syntax error

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jestjs

I am new to jest and want to test my react.js app.
I am following a book, React.js Essentials for jest part.

Here is my test code, Button-test.js

```
jest.dontMock('../Button.react');

describe('Button component', function () {
  it('calls handler function on click', function () {
    var React = require('react');
    var TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');
    var Button = require('../Button.react');
    var handleClick = jest.genMockFunction();

    var button = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Button handleClick={handleClick}/>
    );

    var buttonInstance =
      TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(button, 'button');

    TestUtils.Simulate.click(buttonInstance);
    expect(handleClick).toBeCalled();
    var numberOfCallsMadeIntoMockFunction =
      handleClick.mock.calls.length;
    expect(numberOfCallsMadeIntoMockFunction).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "snapterest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^6.0.1",
    "babelify": "^6.2.0",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "jest-cli": "^0.8.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.0-beta3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0-beta3",
    "snapkite-stream-client": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "testFileExtensions": ["es6", "js"],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react"
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is, when I run npm test, it reports the following syntax error. I think babel-jest is installed, and I have no idea why the syntax error is still there. Are there anything else I need to do except installing babel-jest?

```
source/components/__tests__/Header-test.js 
● Runtime Error
SyntaxError:        
/snapterest/source/components/__tests__/Header-test.js: Unexpected token (11:6)
   9 |    
  10 |     var button = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
> 11 |       <Button handleClick={handleClick}/>
     |       ^
  12 |     );
```

Answer (score 3):

are you using babelify v7? if so, you may have followed the fix mentioned [here](https://github.com/fedosejev/react-essentials) that adds the react preset in your gulpfile. The same thing needs to happen with the test, but since this is run separately you can add this to a .babelrc file in root of your project:

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

*npm test* should then work correctly.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Only I added `"babel": { "presets": [ "react" ] }` to my `package.json` file.

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install react-addons-test-utils babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save-dev
```

http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#content